# Programmatically determine text size in ImageMagick

Tags: graphics, fonts, imagemagick-convert, appearance

I know one way to determine the text of a string, in a particular font and font size, without line breaks: use `convert` to create a new image containing only that string, and then examine the created image for its dimensions. *In other words, I will be extremely surprised if this is the best way.*

What is the preferred way to calculate what the dimensions of a one-line string/font/font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best guide to this is Anthony Thyssen's excellent **ImageMagick Usage** pages, specifically [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text) and then search on that page for the word *"Metrics"*.

Here is an example command and output:

```
convert -debug annotate  xc: -pointsize 36 -annotate 0 'Get my metrics' null: 2>&1 | grep Metrics: | fmt -w80

Metrics: text: Get my metrics; width: 241; height: 41; ascent: 33; descent:
-8; max advance: 72; bounds: 1.10938,-7  16.6094,19; origin: 242,0; pixels per
em: 36,36; underline position: -4.5625; underline thickness: 2.34375
```

Comment: One added comment: After under five minutes of reading quaint typography in Liberation Serif, I saved a local copy, changed only by setting the background to white and the body font to `Verdana, Arial, sans`... and now I can actually **read** it... Is there an appropriate way to suggest the page be presented with a less distracting background color and font?